# Mark a large number of files as Build Action "None" in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio

I have a folder containing 12000 images. When I add them to my project they get marked as Resources, but I want to set their Build Action to None. If I select them all and go to the Properties tab and set None, VS starts working and engulfes itself.

Is there another way to do that? Or a way to set the default Build Action for newly added files to None?

Thank you!

Comment: You can probably open the project file, select the range where these files are and do a find-replace

Comment: In the *.csproj file I have a lot of tags like:

<Resource Include="Resources\Folder\HQ_28000001_11_F.jpg" />

how am I supposed to change it to?

Comment: (this is why this is a comment and not an answer) Change one, observe the difference, and replicate it for the other 11999. :) (Bonus: Then answer your own question below with exactly what you did to help the next person around)

Comment: Why do you want to include those images in your project?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Make a backup of your project file (e.g. by committing it to a branch in source control locally) before making manual changes to the file.**

1. Right click the project node in **Solution Explorer** and click **Unload Project**.
2. Right click the project node in **Solution Explorer** and click **Edit *yourproject*.csproj**.
3. Replace all instances of

   ```
   <Resource Include="Resources\
   ```

   with

   ```
   <None Include="Resources\
   ```
4. Save and close the project file.
5. Right click the project node in **Solution Explorer** and click **Reload Project**.

Optionally you could also remove all instances of these lines and use the following single line instead. You'll definitely want to mark your place in source control so you could undo the change if it doesn't work out like you expect.

```
<None Include="Resources\**\*.jpg"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

12,000 files is a good two orders of magnitude beyond what you can reasonably expect to be performant during a build.  Just checking if files need to copied can easily take 5 minutes on a spindle drive.  Still uncomfortable on a solid-state drive.

You'll need a drastically different approach to solve this.  Key approach is that you don't wait for it so cannot get annoyed at the delay.  Like spinning this off into a separate project that builds a resource DLL, not included in the solution.  Preferably done on another machine, build servers are good for that.  Or a completely different approach to packing the files, like sticking them in a ZIP archive.  A "wad" in gaming speak of old.  Or taking your program to the files instead of the other way around, keeping them stored on disk and telling your code where to find them with a configuration setting.